# Adding a custom action on ListView in Lightning Community

Tags: lightning, community, visual-workflow

**Problem**

I have a `Leads` listview component on Lightning community page. I need to display a button/action on the ListView, that would run a `flow`, I couldn't see the flow type action button in the `List View Actions in Lightning Experience` dual-listbox after following the steps given in the [**docs**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:navigateToURL/documentation).

**What did I try?**

- since the `lightning actions` were not appearing in that list with flow/lightning-component, I created a `URL` type listview button, and provided my flow url in the button . This button was available in the listview edit options now(see below).

[image]

**On the platform, it worked!** and ran the flow, but I had to implement the same on the community, and for some reason it just didn't work in the community. Button click just wouldn't do anything.

While, I am looking for an *overkill solution*(see notes below), is there a workaround to this problem.  :-D

~*Overkill solution: - Creating a lightning component with button and `onclick` of that button flow will be fired. Finally, put that component on the top of community page*.

Comment: So just to be clear, the button shows up, however, the URL redirect to initiate the flow isn't working. Can you see if an error is being throw in the browser's developer console?

Comment: Dev console shows nothing; its blank.

Comment: Hi, did you ever discover a solution other than wrapping the flow in a lightning component?

Comment: @CGI-BIN no. That's the only way I found to solve this specific problem.